# Drawing lines behind textbox C#

Tags: c#, drawing, richtextbox

I am working on creating a simple notebook application. I have been asked to make the input area look like a sheet of notebook paper, with the text sitting on light blue lines. I am trying to make this work, but it seems to be failing miserably.

So far, I have created a transparent RichTextBox that sits on top of a panel. The Text Box is:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class TransparentTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public TransparentTextBox()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, false);
    }
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams parms = base.CreateParams;
            parms.ExStyle |= 0x20;  // Turn on WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return parms;
        }
    }
}
```

The paint code for the panel:

```
private void paper_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.Clear(Color.White);
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.LightPink, 2), 20, 0, 20, paper.Height);
    int h = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Testj", txtBody.Font).Height;
    for (int x = 2 + h; x < paper.Height; x += h)
    {
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.LightSkyBlue, 2), 0, x, paper.Width, x);
    }
}
```

The lines are static, and they will grow to fit any font size/family that is chosen. The problem is when the text box is scrolled. The lines won't move with the text. I have tried to link the handle of the scroll bar to the lines, but they don't seem to be linking properly.

The code to get the current scroll position:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

```
public struct SCROLLINFO
{
    public int cbSize;
    public uint fMask;
    public int nMin;
    public int nMax;
    public uint nPage;
    public int nPos;
    public int nTrackPos;
}

public enum ScrollBarDirection
{
    SB_HORZ = 0,
    SB_VERT = 1,
    SB_CTL = 2,
    SB_BOTH = 3
}

public enum ScrollInfoMask
{
    SIF_RANGE = 0x1,
    SIF_PAGE = 0x2,
    SIF_POS = 0x4,
    SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL = 0x8,
    SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x10,
    SIF_ALL = SIF_RANGE + SIF_PAGE + SIF_POS + SIF_TRACKPOS
}

...


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetScrollInfo")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetScrollInfo([In]IntPtr hwnd, [In]int fnBar, [In, Out]ref SCROLLINFO lpsi);

...

    private void txtBody_VScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inf.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(inf);
        inf.fMask = (int)ScrollInfoMask.SIF_ALL;
        GetScrollInfo(txtBody.Handle, 1, ref inf);
        Console.WriteLine(inf.nTrackPos + ":" + inf.nPos + ":" + TextRenderer.MeasureText("Testj", txtBody.Font).Height);
        paper.Invalidate();
    }
```

Then the paint above was modified to use this:

```
for (int x = inf.nPos % h; x < paper.Height; x += h)
{
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.LightSkyBlue, 2), 0, x, paper.Width, x);
}
```

I also tried to use nTrackPos, but neither seemed to follow the text like I want it to. I'm not too familiar with C#, so I wanted to know what I am missing/could do better. I am using Visual Studio 2008, with Visual C# 2008. .Net framework 3.5 SP1

Comment: Maybe you can draw the lines inside the richtextbox...

Comment: I have tried doing that as well, the problem is they still don't follow the lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is what I came up with after some intensive googling. I decided to follow more into Gusman's comment on my question and look into drawing on the textbox again. After some playing, I realized I was improperly calculating the position of the start line. So, I reconfigured my custom RichTextBox to look like:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Journal
{
    class CustomRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {
        private const int WM_HSCROLL      = 0x114;
        private const int WM_VSCROLL      = 0x115;
        private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL   = 0x20A;
        private const int WM_PAINT        = 0x00F;
        private const int EM_GETSCROLLPOS = 0x4DD;
        public int lineOffset = 0;

       [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(
              IntPtr hWnd,
              int Msg,
              IntPtr wParam,
              ref Point lParam 
              );

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);

            if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
            {
                using (Graphics g = base.CreateGraphics())
                {
                    Point p = new Point();

                    //get the position of the scrollbar to calculate the offset
                    SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_GETSCROLLPOS, IntPtr.Zero, ref p);

                    //draw the pink line on the side
                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.LightPink, 2), 0, 0, 0, this.Height);

                    //determine how tall the text will be per line
                    int h = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Testj", this.Font).Height;

                    //calculate where the lines need to start
                    lineOffset = h - (p.Y % h);

                    //draw lines until there is no more box
                    for (int x = lineOffset; x < Height; x += h)
                    {
                        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.LightSkyBlue, 2), 0, x, Width, x);
                    }

                    //force the panel under us to draw itself.
                    Parent.Invalidate();
                }
            }

        }

        public CustomRichTextBox()
        {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        }

    }
}
```

I then set this box inside of a panel to get the padding I want. The panel is forced to redraw itself with the text box.